# Applying Function on all columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, function, optimization, google-bigquery, multiple-columns

I have a table with more than 100 columns c1,c2,c3....c200 and I want to apply function (assume MAX) on all columns. I can compose my query for each column, but I cannot use * for which BigQuery throws this error `Argument * can only be used in COUNT(*)`

This Query format works but my query size will be much bigger and it is proportional to number of columns.

```
SELECT max(c1) as c1, max(c2) as c2 .... max(c200) as c200 FROM `MYTABLE` group by user
```

Can I write query in a shorter form ?

Comment: Probably a problem with the data format.  If the values were in separate *rows* in a table, then your query would be much simpler.

Comment: We can assume all columns are of the same type. How would you write it differently ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you meant when you said "If the values were in separate rows in a table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL and avoids to call out all columns by names but as a side-effect result is just one comma separated list of max values in order of respective columns

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(max_val AS STRING) ORDER BY pos) max_values
FROM (
  SELECT pos, MAX(CAST(val AS INT64)) max_val
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'".+?":([^,}]+)')) val WITH OFFSET pos
  GROUP BY pos
)
```

In above example I assume columns are all of INT64 datatype

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 1, 22
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(max_val AS STRING) ORDER BY pos) max_values
FROM (
  SELECT pos, MAX(CAST(val AS INT64)) max_val
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'".+?":([^,}]+)')) val WITH OFFSET pos
  GROUP BY pos
)
```

with result

```
Row max_values   
1   11,2,22
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Thanks a lot. Can we also preserve column names ? Is * exclusively for count ? Will * work with UDFs ?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a data set as parameter for your function, does your function accept a data set as its input parameter? If not, you get the error of course.
You can try like this:

```
select
(select max(c1) from mytable) max_c1,
(select max(c2) from mytable) max_c2

from dual
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes my function dataset as input parameter. What I would like to achieve is to write short query when I know I will be applying same function across all columns. In your example you had to write `(select max(something) from mytable)` as the number of columns. This is what I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Once you harness the power of dynamically query generation, you will love Bigquery even more:

You can literally create the sql first by another wrapper sql like this:

```
select concat("select ", string_agg(selected_columns), " from `{YOUR_TABLE_NAME}`")  
from (select concat("max(", column_name, ") as ", column_name) as selected_columns from  (select 'column_prefix'|| num as column_name 
from (select generate_array(1, 200) as num_column) as a, unnest (num_column) as num))
```

Below is the sql that will get generated from above that you want to run as per your ask:

```
select max(column_prefix1) as column_prefix1,max(column_prefix2) as column_prefix2,max(column_prefix3) as column_prefix3,max(column_prefix4) as column_prefix4,max(column_prefix5) as column_prefix5,max(column_prefix6) as column_prefix6,...,max(column_prefix200) as column_prefix200 from `{YOUR_TABLE_NAME}`
```

Now you can copy paste above sql and get your results.

(This assumes your column numbers are without any gaps)